# TypeError (no marshal_dump is defined for class OpenSSL::Digest::Digest) on EngineYard Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, engineyard

Our app runs without issue in development and test (all rspec and cucumber tests run)

When deployed to EngineYard Cloud, however, I repeatedly get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message.

When I receive the error, tailing the log files tells me the page rendered successfully, with one caveat.

```
Completed 200 OK in 1833ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)

TypeError (no marshal_dump is defined for class OpenSSL::Digest::Digest):
```

I have seen some postings on the TypeError, but nothing that seems to fit this situation.

I would be grateful for some suggestions on how I might track down what is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. I was accidentally storing a model instance in session, and the model had encrypted values.

I am now, properly, only storing the id of the model, and the issue has abated.